# Agrupar valores distintos dos dias por mês (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma consulta para fazer, parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo pensar numa maneira de fazer funcionar rs
Tenho que selecionar valores distintos por dia e agrupa-los por mês...
Por exemplo, um paciente passa por um hospital 10x no dia de hoje, porém no select ele tem q ser somado somente 1x (vale lembrar que o select é a partir da tabela de atendimentos). Segue select

```
select to_char(a.dt_atendimento, 'MM') mes,
           to_char(a.dt_atendimento, 'DD') dia,
           count(distinct a.cd_paciente) qtd
      from atendime a
     where to_char(a.dt_atendimento, 'RRRR') = '2019'
     group by to_char(a.dt_atendimento, 'MM'),
              to_char(a.dt_atendimento, 'DD')
     order by 1, 2
```

Uma parte do resultado é este

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço :)

Comment: E qual o problema que você tá encontrando na sua `query`? Consegue fazer um exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4)?

Comment: Utilizar o SELECT acima como uma suquery e a query externa agregar a quantidade apenas por mês não resolveria?

Comment: @Sorack na verdade eu tenho que "ignorar" o valor da coluna dia, mas não posso ignora-la no código, pois preciso dos valores distintos por dia... Ou seja, preciso retira-la e agrupar somente por mês, mas o numero distintos por dia é necessário.

Comment: @ÍtaloSalgado Entendi, tem uma solução simples pra isso

Comment: @anonimo infelizmente foi minha primeira tentativa, ele continua trazendo vários resultados para o mês 01, por exemplo, trás 30 linhas 011 com o valor de cada dia, só nao exibe a coluna

Comment: @Sorack me de uma luz, por favor kkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente utilizar sua `query` acima dentro de outro agrupamento em conjunto com o `SUM`:

```
SELECT x.mes,
       SUM(x.qtd) AS qtd
  FROM (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(a.dt_atendimento, 'MM') AS mes,
         TO_CHAR(a.dt_atendimento, 'DD') AS dia,
         COUNT(distinct a.cd_paciente) AS qtd
    FROM atendime a
   WHERE TO_CHAR(a.dt_atendimento, 'RRRR') = '2019'
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(a.dt_atendimento, 'MM'),
            TO_CHAR(a.dt_atendimento, 'DD')
   ORDER BY 1, 2) x
 GROUP BY x.mes
```

Comment: Rapaz, era mais simples que o esperado... Eu cheguei a fazer algo parecido, porém eu agrupava também pela qtd kkkk erro de principiante. Muito obrigado!